# Consistent hashing domino effect

Tags: cassandra, consistent-hashing

I'm trying to figure out how a system like Cassandra which uses consistent hashing handles cascading node failures. I know there's this concept of virtual nodes and keys are mapped to virtual nodes. Virtual nodes are in turn mapped to actual physical nodes, the idea being that each physical nodes gets an equal share of the keyspace. My question is the following: what happens when a physical node goes down? All the virtual nodes that are on this physical node will need to be moved over to another physical node. Wont this lead to a domino effect which could overload other nodes in the cluster? How do real life systems handle cases like this?

Answer (score 1):

When node goes down, there is no automatic movement of the token ranges. If node is completely down, token range rebalance should be triggered manually by removing the node, or assassinating it.

When node that is responsible for some token ranges is going down, its replicas continue to serve the traffic.

Comment: Hey Alex i am not the OP but curious about related topic; 3 nodes, RF 1, %33 each - one node is down (we couldn't recover it) - when we remove the gone node from the ring - is it going to re-distribute rest of %66 as %100 between two nodes to %50/%50 each and we will lost %33 of the data right ?

Comment: If you have RF=1, data is gone completely... if you have RF > 1, the replica that is left will be source for creating an additional copy

Comment: thanks Alex - but wont this cause the replicas to now serve a lot more traffic, potentially causing it to fail and so on..? maybe we can solve this by careful provisioning?

Comment: yes, you need to size the cluster to handle failing replicas, etc. Traffic always have spikes, and cluster should be able to handle +20-30% of the normal traffic. I recommend to use NoSQLBench tool for such sizing exercise